# How to make a private API call to Coinsbit using Python

Tags: python, cryptocurrency

I'm trying to make a private API call to Coinsbit using Python, but I'm having some trouble. I have already successfully implemented the public API calls, but I'm struggling with the authentication required for the private endpoints.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import requests
import json
import time
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64

def call_api():
    api_key = 'API_KEY'
    api_secret = 'SECRET_KEY'
    request = '/api/v1/account/order_history' # /api/v1/order/new
    base_url = 'https://api.coinsbit.io/'

    data = {
        'request': request,
        'nonce': str(int(time.time())),
    }

    complete_url = base_url + request
    data_json_str = json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':'), ensure_ascii=False)
    payload = base64.b64encode(data_json_str.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
    signature = hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), payload.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()

    headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'X-TXC-APIKEY': api_key,
        'X-TXC-PAYLOAD': payload,
        'X-TXC-SIGNATURE': signature
    }

    try:
        res = requests.post(complete_url, headers=headers, data=data_json_str)
        res.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        return {'error': str(e)}

    return {'result': res.json()}

print(call_api())
```

When I execute the code, I'm getting an error. I have double-checked my API key and secret key, and they are correct. I suspect there might be an issue with how I'm generating the signature or setting the headers.

I am seeking insights on what I might be doing wrong or how I can troubleshoot this issue. Additionally, are there any specific requirements or headers that I need to set for the Coinsbit private API calls?

Comment: What kind of message do you receive when execute the code?

Comment: When u merge `base_url` and `request` your complate_url becomes `https://api.coinsbit.io//api/v1/account/order_history` with double `/`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working one:

```py
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac
import json
import time

import requests


def call_api():
    api_key = "API_KEY"
    api_secret = "API_SECRET"
    request = "/api/v1/account/order_history"
    base_url = "https://api.coinsbit.io" # "/" removed

    data = {
        "request": request,
        "nonce": str(int(time.time() * 1000)),  # * 1000 added
    }

    complete_url = base_url + request
    data_json_str = json.dumps(data, separators=(",", ":"), ensure_ascii=False)
    payload = base64.b64encode(data_json_str.encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8")
    signature = hmac.new(
        api_secret.encode("utf-8"), payload.encode("utf-8"), hashlib.sha512
    ).hexdigest()

    headers = {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "X-TXC-APIKEY": api_key,
        "X-TXC-PAYLOAD": payload,
        "X-TXC-SIGNATURE": signature,
    }

    try:
        res = requests.post(complete_url, headers=headers, data=data_json_str)
        res.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        return {"error": str(e)}

    return {"result": res.json()}


print(call_api())
```